# When adding files via the NuGet package explorer, which do I need to add?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Creating a package via the command line doesn't work for me, so I tried the GUI downloaded from here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/using-a-gui-to-build-packages

This has created a package which I can install in other projects. Hurrah!

My question is this. In the GUI, I have to drag the files I want into the 'Package contents' window. So I've dragged literally everything in the projects /bin/Release folder. I'm guessing not everything is required. For example, there are subfolders in there called 'de', 'es' etc. Do I really need those?

Can anyone provide any guidance about what should be added and what should not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you add the .dlls to the lib folder. And the content in sub folders in de es etc. are localized resources.

NuGet support the use of satellite packages for installing/running on localized platforms.

For more information, please refer to:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-localized-packages